# Автокомплит на сайте

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Добрый день. 
Подскажите кто знает каким образом можно сделать автокомплит на сайте?
Чтобы реализовать в поиске автокомплит города или аэропорта, используется запрос следующего вида:

[http://autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=Мос&callback=function](http://autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&q=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81&callback=function)

где
q — основной параметр, задается в виде текста;
locale — язык вывода;
with_countries — используется, если автокомплит создается для страны (false — ответ не содержит информацию о стране, true — ответ содержит информацию о стране);
callback — название функции, в которой возвращается ответ.

Пример ответа:

```
[
  {
    "_id":"4eda5f858792904be4001433",
    "coordinates":{
      "lon":37.617633,
      "lat":55.755786
    },
    "city_fullname":"Москва, Россия",
    "city_code":"MOW",
    "name":null,
    "_type":"city",
    "_score":67.74186,
    "city_name":"Москва",
    "title":"Москва",
    "country_code":"RU",
    "country_name":"Россия",
    "code":"MOW"
  },
  {
    "_id":"4eda61628792904be4003b20",
    "coordinates":{
      "lon":43.149445,
      "lat":36.3075
    },
    "city_fullname":"Мосул, Ирак",
    "city_code":"OSM",
    "name":"Мосул",
    "_type":"airport",
    "_score":26.681381,
    "city_name":"Мосул",
    "title":"Мосул",
    "country_code":"IQ",
    "country_name":"Ирак",
    "code":"OSM"
}]
```

вот пример кода как я пытаюсь сделать:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>

    <body>
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
       source: function(request, response){ 
        $.ajax({
              url: "http://autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false&callback=function",
             dataType: "jsonp",

             data:{
                 q: request.term
              },
             success: function(data){

             response($.map(data, function(item){
             alert(data);
                      }));
                 }
             });
          },
          minLength: 2
          });
          });
  </script>
  <input id="test">
  </body>
  </html>
```

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow!

Comment: добавьте в вопрос (кнопка "править") ваш код с разметкой и покажите какой код вы писали для того, чтобы сделать автокомплит

Comment: почему у вас в вопросе написано, что основной параметр `q`, а в коде передаете `d` ?

Comment: а в примере ответа у вас просто массив, а в коде вы обрабатываете `data.geonames`

Comment: Я сделал запускающию версию проверьте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочая версия

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#test" ).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://autocomplete.travelpayouts.com/jravia?locale=ru&with_countries=false',
                    data:{ q: request.term },
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(v,i){
                            var name = v.name || " ";
                            var text = v.city_fullname + ', ' + name ;
                            return text;
                        }));
    
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
      });
```

```html
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<input id="test" />
```

Comment: Благодарю за рабочую версию. Там только пришлось поправить: удалить из ссылки параметр q и добавить в скрипт         data:{
                            q: request.term
                        },

Comment: Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня не получается таким же образом сделать автокомплит используя другую ссылку (http://engine.hotellook.com/api/v2/lookup.json?query=moscow&lang=ru&lookFor=hotel&limit=1)

Comment: откройте новый вопрос, напишите что это это json а не jsonp, я на него отвечу. вставте этот код как пример